# Oracle SQL Developer InvocationTargetException while trying to export data

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I used to export data easyly from the result of a query in Oracle SQL Developer. Since last week i get an error everytime i try to export the results. I didn't change any settings. The error i get is:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at oracle.ide.panels.MetaTraversable.newTraversable(MetaTraversable.java:315)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.Step.newTraversable(Step.java:171)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMStateInfo.getTraversable(FSMStateInfo.java:99)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard._addPage(FSMWizard.java:580)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard._populatePages(FSMWizard.java:534)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard.(FSMWizard.java:121)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizMain.launchWizard(ExportWizMain.java:226)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizMain.launchForGrid(ExportWizMain.java:204)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.actions.TableExportAction.launchForGrid(TableExportAction.java:73)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.contextmenu.ExportGrid$1.actionPerformed(ExportGrid.java:165)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(URLFileChooser.java:495)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setToFirstContextPathDirectory(URLFileChooser.java:1479)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setCurrentDirectoryFromPathContext(URLFileChooser.java:1455)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setDefaultPathContext(URLFileChooser.java:1521)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:129)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:113)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:109)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:105)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser$URLFileChooserPanel.(URLFileChooser.java:819)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser$URLFileChooserPanel.(URLFileChooser.java:877)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.createURLFileChooserPanel(URLFileChooser.java:782)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.TargetOptionsPanel.initFilePanel(TargetOptionsPanel.java:237)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.TargetOptionsPanel.(TargetOptionsPanel.java:63)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.TargetOptionsPanel.(TargetOptionsPanel.java:55)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizDestinstaionPanel.(ExportWizDestinstaionPanel.java:97)
>       ... 54 more
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(URLFileChooser.java:495)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setToFirstContextPathDirectory(URLFileChooser.java:1479)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setCurrentDirectoryFromPathContext(URLFileChooser.java:1455)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.setDefaultPathContext(URLFileChooser.java:1521)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:129)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:113)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:109)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.(URLFileChooser.java:105)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser$URLFileChooserPanel.(URLFileChooser.java:819)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser$URLFileChooserPanel.(URLFileChooser.java:877)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.ui.URLFileChooser.createURLFileChooserPanel(URLFileChooser.java:782)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.TargetOptionsPanel.initFilePanel(TargetOptionsPanel.java:237)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.TargetOptionsPanel.(TargetOptionsPanel.java:63)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.TargetOptionsPanel.(TargetOptionsPanel.java:55)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizDestinstaionPanel.(ExportWizDestinstaionPanel.java:97)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at oracle.ide.panels.MetaTraversable.newTraversable(MetaTraversable.java:315)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.Step.newTraversable(Step.java:171)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMStateInfo.getTraversable(FSMStateInfo.java:99)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard._addPage(FSMWizard.java:580)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard._populatePages(FSMWizard.java:534)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard.(FSMWizard.java:121)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizMain.launchWizard(ExportWizMain.java:226)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizMain.launchForGrid(ExportWizMain.java:204)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.actions.TableExportAction.launchForGrid(TableExportAction.java:73)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.contextmenu.ExportGrid$1.actionPerformed(ExportGrid.java:165)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

And under details i get the following Excetion-Stacktrace:

> oracle.ide.panels.TraversalException: Internal error in FSM: Übergang nicht gefunden: 
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard.handleFSMTransitionException(FSMWizard.java:1225)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard._canTraverseFSM(FSMWizard.java:805)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard._validateFSMState(FSMWizard.java:671)
>       at oracle.ide.wizard.FSMWizard.selectPage(FSMWizard.java:453)
>       at oracle.bali.ewt.wizard.WizardRoadMap$Listener$1.run(WizardRoadMap.java:1157)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
>       at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
>       at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
>       at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
>       at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
>       at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
>       at oracle.bali.ewt.wizard.WizardDialog.runDialog(WizardDialog.java:382)
>       at oracle.bali.ewt.wizard.WizardDialog.runDialog(WizardDialog.java:298)
>       at oracle.ide.dialogs.WizardLauncher.runDialog(WizardLauncher.java:51)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizMain.launchWizard(ExportWizMain.java:251)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.wizard.ExportWizMain.launchForGrid(ExportWizMain.java:204)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.actions.TableExportAction.launchForGrid(TableExportAction.java:73)
>       at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.grid.contextmenu.ExportGrid$1.actionPerformed(ExportGrid.java:165)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
>       at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Any idea how to get this solved?

Comment: I don't know what version or what OS you're running, on, but try to find your system.x.y.z where x.y.z = your SQLDev version - this is where all of the application settings are stored on your machine, and rename it. if on windows, it'll be on AppData, Roaming Profiles, SQL Developer folder

Answer (score 1):

to me this is a memory issue. I shutdown all other apps and restarted sql developer and the issue was gone.

Comment: i don't think this was memory related, there's nothing in your error stack to indicate the jvm was exhausted

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while exporting the file in CSV format. I spent 2 days to for finding a solution for this but didn't find any useful resource online. So, I did the following to solve this.

> What Went Wrong is I have given the wrong Naming convention. Given " : " (colon) symbol while saving the file.
>   So in order to resolve, go to the path where we usually save the export file in my case it is "C:\Users\admin\export.sql" the path.
>   From here delete the file which you have saved by giving " : " (colon).
>   That's it solves the above exception and you export will work properly.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Jaguars Member Posts: 11
Feb 3, 2019 2:40AM edited Feb 3, 2019 2:40AM
nevermind...Added below to SQL Developer installation's sqldeveloper.conf file:

AddVMOption -Dide.user.dir=C:/SQLDev/.sqldeveloper

Works fine now.

[https://www.databaseadm.com/article/14124622/Encountering+error+%22URI+has+an+authority+component%22+on+certain+SQLDev+o…](https://www.databaseadm.com/article/14124622/Encountering+error+%22URI+has+an+authority+component%22+on+certain+SQLDev+o%E2%80%A6)

Share on Twitter

Comment: I take this solution from Oracle community, tried by myself and works!, last time when crash was running, cannot export connection config even so.

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary parts of your answer and add an explanation, how and why it works instead for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the recent files you have downloaded (exported) even from recycle bin itself... It will work for sure !! I did that

This issue comes only when you download file with some wrong extention like DAT file etc... So delete all recent files